# Passing a numpy array to C++

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, cython

I have some code writen in Python for which the output is a numpy array, and now I want to send that output to `C++` code, where the heavy part of the calculations will be performed.

I have tried using cython's `public cdef`, but I am running on some issues. I would appreciate your help! Here goes my code:

`pymodule.pyx`:

```
from pythonmodule import result # result is my numpy array
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef public void cfunc():
    print 'I am in here!!!'
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2, mode='c'] res = result
    print res
```

Once this is cythonized, I call:

`pymain.c`:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include "pymodule.h"

int main() {
  Py_Initialize();
  initpymodule();
  test(2);
  Py_Finalize();
}

int test(int a)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    initpymodule();
    cfunc();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting a `NameError` for the `result` variable at `C++`. I have tried defining it with pointers and calling it indirectly from other functions, but the array remains invisible. I am pretty sure the answer is quite simple, but I just do not get it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add the error message

Comment: Do you really want to embed the Python Interpreter in `C++` or do you just want to pass a numpy array, do some calculation and then continue working in `Python`?

Comment: @DomTomCat The error is `Exception NameError: "name 'result' is not defined" in 'pymodule.cfunc' ignored`. @Jim I just want to pass the numpy array. In general, I have some routines running on python that are useful and would like to pass the results (usually numpy arrays) to a more efficient block of code, in C++ or Fortran, that performs the really demanding calculations. Once this works, I will compile it to a library to call it when needed.

Answer (score 9):

#### Short Answer

The NameError was cause by the fact that Python couldn't find the module, the working directory isn't automatically added to your [**`PYTHONPATH`**](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH). Using [**`setenv`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) with `setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);` in your `C/C++` code fixes this.

#### Longer Answer

There's an easy way to do this, apparently. With a python module `pythonmodule.py` containing an already created array:

```
import numpy as np

result = np.arange(20, dtype=np.float).reshape((2, 10))
```

You can structure your `pymodule.pyx` to export that array by using the **[`public`](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c)** keyword. By adding some auxiliary functions, you'll generally won't need to touch neither the Python, nor the Numpy `C-API`:

```
from pythonmodule import result
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


cdef public np.ndarray getNPArray():
    """ Return array from pythonmodule. """
    return <np.ndarray>result

cdef public int getShape(np.ndarray arr, int shape):
    """ Return Shape of the Array based on shape par value. """
    return <int>arr.shape[1] if shape else <int>arr.shape[0]

cdef public void copyData(float *** dst, np.ndarray src):
    """ Copy data from src numpy array to dst. """
    cdef float **tmp
    cdef int i, j, m = src.shape[0], n=src.shape[1];

    # Allocate initial pointer 
    tmp = <float **>malloc(m * sizeof(float *))
    if not tmp:
        raise MemoryError()

    # Allocate rows
    for j in range(m):
        tmp[j] = <float *>malloc(n * sizeof(float))
        if not tmp[j]:
            raise MemoryError()

    # Copy numpy Array
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            tmp[i][j] = src[i, j]

    # Assign pointer to dst
    dst[0] = tmp
```

Function `getNPArray` and `getShape` return the array and its shape, respectively. `copyData` was added in order to just extract the [**`ndarray.data`**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.data.html#numpy-ndarray-data) and copy it so you can then finalize Python and work without having the interpreter initialized.

A sample program (in `C`, `C++` should look identical) would look like this:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
#include "pyxmod.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(float **arr, int m, int n);
void getArray(float ***arr, int * m, int * n);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    // Holds data and shapes.
    float **data = NULL;
    int m, n;

    // Gets array and then prints it.
    getArray(&data, &m, &n);
    printArray(data, m, n);

    return 0;
}

void getArray(float ***data, int * m, int * n){
    // setenv is important, makes python find 
    // modules in working directory
    setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);

    // Initialize interpreter and module
    Py_Initialize();
    initpyxmod();

    // Use Cython functions.
    PyArrayObject *arr = getNPArray();
    *m = getShape(arr, 0);
    *n = getShape(arr, 1);

    copyData(data, arr);

    if (data == NULL){  //really redundant.
        fprintf(stderr, "Data is NULL\n");
        return ;
    }

    Py_DECREF(arr);
    Py_Finalize();
}

void printArray(float **arr, int m, int n){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i < m; i++){
        for(j=0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%f ", arr[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Always remember to set:

```
setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);
```

**before** you call `Py_Initialize` so Python can find modules in the working directory.

The rest is pretty straight-forward. It might need some additional error-checking and **definitely** needs a function to free the allocated memmory.

#### Alternate Way w/o Cython:

Doing it the way you are attempting is way hassle than it's worth, you would probably be better off using [`numpy.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) to save your array in a `npy` binary file and then use some [*C++ library that reads that file for you*](https://github.com/rogersce/cnpy).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @Jim. I have seen the tutorial you are suggesting, though it is not exactly what I want to do. I would like to pass the numpy array to C++ and keep working on C++, not python.

Comment: I think I am going to try embedding Python in C++. Something like [this](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) perhaps. Seems to be the best way to do it.

Comment: @user3225486 I updated the answer with a possible solution through Cython. I think it will work for you this way.